# Unity/2015 Macbook Pro (Retina) Build Has Different View Than Simulator View

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[I've been through a few of the suggestions that have been posted recently, some suggesting to switch the Canvas UI from `Constant Pixel` size to `Scale With Screen Size`](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/953327/unity-5-ui-fill-any-screen.html), but this is not working.  No matter what I seem to do, I can't get the content to display in the build window the same way it did in the Unity simulator.  I'm new to Unity and game design, so please forgive me if I'm missing the obvious.

Also, a sidenote, my fonts seem to be much fuzzier than I would expect.  I have to crank down the character size to almost the bare minimum, then increase the font size a ton for them to be even halfway decent.

[image: Simulated Version]
[image: Build Version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with the fact that your unity editor is set to free aspect. 
[image]

This means that you can resize the editor however you want and it will change the resolution but ONLY in the editor itself. If you want to fix that, you can click where it says "Free Aspect" and either set it to a ratio (like 5:4, or any of the default options) or you can click the plus bottom at the bottom of the list and add a fixed ratio so you can see exactly what it would look like with that screen resolution.

[image]

Obviously change the width and height to what you want. Then make sure you select that. That will make the editor show you exactly what will show in the build for that resolution.

Once this is done you change actually change the build settings so it only runs in that resolution for the build as well.

As for the text being fuzzy, I have always had to do what you did as well, so sadly no help from me there.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Such a quick and instant fix!  Very much appreciated!